# Build a Query from User Input - Too Many Permutations of If Logic

Tags: soql, conditional

I have a Visualforce page that allows users to filter a list records based their filter criteria.

My issue is that I end up having to make a permutation for every possible combination of their selection. Imagine ten fields with three values (null,true, false)

This leads to a giant railroad yard of if statement logic blocks and queries. As more fields are added or requested to be filtered by.... this gets out of hand.

There has to be a better way to write this.

EXAMPLE:

```
public boolean gender {get; set;}
public boolean veteran {get; set;}
public boolean disabled {get; set;}
public boolean hispanic {get; set;}
public boolean felon {get; set;}
public boolean balding {get; set;}
public boolean fat ...... etc...

if(gender == true && veteran == false ..... etc.) {
  query = etc....
}
if(gender == false && veteran == false ..... etc.) {
  query = etc....
}
if(gender == null && veteran == false ..... etc.) {
  query = etc....
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what we call "[Dynamic SOQL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_soql.htm)". Basically, you just build a raw string and pass it to Database.query:

```
String[] filters = new String[0];
if(gender != null) {
  filters.add('Gender__c = :gender');
}
if(veteran != null) {
  filters.add('Veteran__c = :veteran');
}
// etc...

SObject[] results = Database.query(
  'SELECT Id, ... FROM Object WHERE '+
  String.join(filters,' AND ')
);
```

Comment: That was my initial thought as well (mostly typed up), though they are `Boolean` fields so it's a little hard to understand why it would even need to be dynamic. I guess just so you don't filter against null?

Comment: @AdrianLarson Boolean probably isn't the ideal example, but imagine a picklist that may or may not have a value, etc.

Comment: Yeah, like I said, I started typing up almost exactly this answer, then the field type made me pause and think. No point posting the same thing. Maybe it's what they need.